# Set alpha on one color in UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have this PNG image: (the area in the grey borders is transparent)

[image]

I would like only the grey corners to have alpha of 0.5

If I set

```
[imgView setAlpha:0.5f];
```

Also the transparent area in the middle retrieves a semi-white color.

How can I do it?

Comment: You'll have to utilize core graphics, and probably do some masking to only apply the transparency to certain areas.

Comment: Is this a static image or do you need a programmatic solution?

Comment: @bgoers I know how to do it with CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors, but then the color is totally transparent. I would like it to be half transparent

Comment: If I understand (now) correctly, you want the white completely transparent while the grey corners should be black with 50% opacity? Again, why don't you just change the image file?

Comment: the grey corners should be grey with 50% opacity. I could do it with photoshop of course, but I have a reason to do it in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason why you don't just change the original image file? If that's not possible, you could put a white (black?) rectangle with 50% opacity below the image.

Of course there are many ways to do this but you would need to tell us more about your use case.

Comment: It will be displayed as a top layer in the camera

Comment: As @Nikolai suggested, I did it in photoshop

Answer (score 0):

You should add one imageview below your desired image. and adjust alpha of that image.

Comment: How would it help with the attached image?